# CoreOS build docker image (CP100A Training)

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently working on the "Google cloud platform fundamentals" labs and I'm running into issues.
Each time I have to use a CoreOS instance to spin up a docker instance there is an error I get.

For example: in the Cloud SQL lab, at some point I have to build a docker image of the folder I just cloned from a git repo using the command:

```
docker build -t cp100/cloudsql-python cp100-cloud-sql-python
```

which gives me a wall of text that ends with an error :

```
 Downloading/unpacking flask
 Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
 Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement flask
 No distributions at all found for flask
 Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log`
```

The thing Is, there is no "/root/.pip/pip.log" file.
So here are my questions :

- Are the tutorials outdated, and if yes, where can I find the up-to-date tutorials?
- Why does it happen? I think It is because pip or Python or both are not installed but shouldn't the command `docker build` take the installation in charge?
- How can I fix it?

the cp100-cloud-sql-python file is available at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatformTraining/cp100-cloud-sql-python.git

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answers by myself:

So the reason it doesn't work is that pip (and easy install) use HTTP and pypi.python.org requires HTTPS, the issue is further documented here :
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1510444

So in order to fix it I modified the Dockerfile inside the app from

```
FROM google/debian:wheezy
MAINTAINER Sharif Salah <sharif.salah+docker@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip python-mysqldb && \
    pip install flask

ADD app /app

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "python", "/app/app.py" ]
```

to

```
FROM google/debian:wheezy
MAINTAINER Sharif Salah <sharif.salah+docker@gmail.com>
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python-dev python-setuptools python-mysqldb && \
    easy_install -i https://pypi.python.org/simple flask
ADD app /app
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "python", "/app/app.py" ]
```

which will force easy_install to use the address specified after the -i.

It worked in my case but as documented on Bugzilla, it may not work for everything.
I hope this will help someone